# How can I close my Modal which is inside another custom component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How can I close my Modal which is inside another custom component?
My modal is in another component. I have a problem passing a state to the parent component. You can see the parent and child component below.

**Parent Component:**

```
const ViewNote = ({route, navigation}) => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  function visibility(cases) {
    setVisible(cases);
    console.log(cases);
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.noteContainer}>

        {/* MODAL */}
        <FancyAlert visible={visible} />
        <View style={styles.deleteContainer}>
          <Pressable android_ripple={{color: '#d9d9d9'}} onPress={() =>  setVisible(true)}>
            <MaterialIcons style={styles.icon} name='delete' size={40}/>
          </Pressable>
        </View>

    </View>
  )
}

export default ViewNote
```

**Child Component:**

```
const FancyAlert = ({visible}) => {
  const [showAlert, setShowAlert] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Modal transparent visible={visible}>
      <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
        <View style={styles.dialogContainer}>
          <Text style={[styles.text, {fontSize: 16}]}>Are you sure you want to delete this note?</Text>

          <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
            <Pressable style={styles.cancel} android_ripple={{color: '#d9d9d9'}} onPress={() => setVisible(false)}>
              <Text style={[styles.text, {fontFamily: 'SofiaProBold'}]}>Cancel</Text>
            </Pressable>
            
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    </Modal>
  )
}

export default FancyAlert
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply pass the "visibility" function as prop for FancyAlert.
Your code should be something like that:

```
const ViewNote = ({route, navigation}) => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  function visibility(cases) {
    setVisible(cases);
    console.log(cases);
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.noteContainer}>

        {/* MODAL */}
        <FancyAlert visible={visible} visibility={visibility} />
        <View style={styles.deleteContainer}>
          <Pressable android_ripple={{color: '#d9d9d9'}} onPress={() =>  visibility(true)}>
            <MaterialIcons style={styles.icon} name='delete' size={40}/>
          </Pressable>
        </View>

    </View>
  )
}

export default ViewNote
```

And than the FencyAlert component should be:

```
const FancyAlert = ({ visible, visibility }) => {
  const [showAlert, setShowAlert] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Modal transparent visible={visible}>
      <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
        <View style={styles.dialogContainer}>
          <Text style={[styles.text, {fontSize: 16}]}>Are you sure you want to delete this note?</Text>

          <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
            <Pressable style={styles.cancel} android_ripple={{color: '#d9d9d9'}} onPress={() => visibility(false)}>
              <Text style={[styles.text, {fontFamily: 'SofiaProBold'}]}>Cancel</Text>
            </Pressable>
            
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    </Modal>
  )
}

export default FancyAlert
```

This should do the job

Comment: This is something that I was looking for. Thank you for your time and answer. Have a great day :)

Comment: I'm glad that it was what you were searching for! :)

Answer (score 2):

Move state to parent component. And pass onClose function.

```
const ViewNote = ({route, navigation}) => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  function visibility(cases) {
    setVisible(cases);
    console.log(cases);
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.noteContainer}>

        {/* MODAL */}
        <FancyAlert visible={visible} onClose={() => setVisible(false)} />
        <View style={styles.deleteContainer}>
          <Pressable android_ripple={{color: '#d9d9d9'}} onPress={() =>  setVisible(true)}>
            <MaterialIcons style={styles.icon} name='delete' size={40}/>
          </Pressable>
        </View>

    </View>
  )
}

export default ViewNote
```

```
const FancyAlert = ({visible, onClose}) => {
 
  return (
    <Modal transparent visible={visible} onClose={onClose}>
      <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
        <View style={styles.dialogContainer}>
          <Text style={[styles.text, {fontSize: 16}]}>Are you sure you want to delete this note?</Text>

          <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
            <Pressable 
              style={styles.cancel} 
              android_ripple={{color: '#d9d9d9'}} 
              onPress={onClose}>
            <Text style={[styles.text, {fontFamily: 'SofiaProBold'}]}>Cancel</Text>
            </Pressable>
            
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    </Modal>
  )
}

export default FancyAlert
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you for your time and answer. Have great day :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass also setVisible to the child component, and invoke it with the value you want.

```
const ViewNote = ({route, navigation}) => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  function visibility(cases) {
    setVisible(cases);
    console.log(cases);
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.noteContainer}>

        {/* MODAL */}
        <FancyAlert visible={visible} setVisible={setVisible} />  //ADDED CODE HERE
        <View style={styles.deleteContainer}>
          <Pressable android_ripple={{color: '#d9d9d9'}} onPress={() =>  setVisible(true)}>
            <MaterialIcons style={styles.icon} name='delete' size={40}/>
          </Pressable>
        </View>

    </View>
  )
}

export default ViewNote
```

and use it as:
Child Component:

```
const FancyAlert = ({visible, setVisible}) => { // IMPORT IT HERE
  const [showAlert, setShowAlert] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Modal transparent visible={visible}>
      <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
        <View style={styles.dialogContainer}>
          <Text style={[styles.text, {fontSize: 16}]}>Are you sure you want to delete this note?</Text>

          <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
            <Pressable style={styles.cancel} android_ripple={{color: '#d9d9d9'}} onPress={() => setVisible(false)}> // NOW THIS WORKS
              <Text style={[styles.text, {fontFamily: 'SofiaProBold'}]}>Cancel</Text>
            </Pressable>
            
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    </Modal>
  )
}

export default FancyAlert
```

Comment: Happy to help. This is the simplest way to pass data to from child to parent component in React .Good luck!